# FullCalendar With maxTime set > 24 Items Past midnight will not render

Tags: javascript, typescript, fullcalendar

I am Configuring the options on fullCalendar to display days starting at 6am and ending 6am the next day.
done through calendarOptions.

```
        this.calendarOptions.minTime = moment.duration(6, 'h');
        this.calendarOptions.maxTime = moment.duration(30, 'h');
        this.calendarOptions.nextDayThreshold = '06:00:00';
```

However Items which start between midnight and 6am are not rendering in the view for either day/week/month. Those timeslots are left empty.

The calendar renders the rows correctly and the hours header renders 6am though 6am the next day correctly

but none of the schedule events between midnight and 6am render on those visible rows.

Is there some extra configuration I need?

Answer (score 0):

It seems there was a bug in fullClendar.js that was causing a miss calculation of the event segment location in the grid for events past midnight.

within TimeGrid.mixin.computeSegVerticals method the date of the event gets passed to the computeDateTop method which is fine for regular midnight to midnight days. For irregular days like mine 6am to 6am what is required is the date of the day we are filling with events so that the co-ordinates are calculated correctly so that we get seg.Top and Bottom time of time + 24 hours. If we don't add the 24 hours the computeTimeTop will calculate -ve slatCoverage which is quashed to zero.

to correct this modify the computeSegVerticals method (approx. line 6220 or if working from source files TimeGrid.events.js line 332)  thus:

```
computeSegVerticals: function(segs) {
    var i, seg;

    for (i = 0; i < segs.length; i++) {
        seg = segs[i];
        //seg.top = this.computeDateTop(seg.start, seg.start);
        //seg.bottom = this.computeDateTop(seg.end, seg.start);
        seg.top = this.computeDateTop(seg.start, this.colData[seg.col].day);
        seg.bottom = this.computeDateTop(seg.end, this.colData[seg.col].day);
    }
},
```

As you can see I am passing in the date of the day column which allows computeDateTop to be calculated correctly for the segments.

Note this only fixes Day/Week views.

The month view still has the same problem and I may look at that next, but its not a priority for me a the moment.

Answer (score 0):

colData does not exit in Ver 2.7.3. 
So I changed

```
computeSegVerticals: function(segs) {
    var i, seg;
    for (i = 0; i < segs.length; i++) {
        seg = segs[i];
        var start = this.dayDates[seg.dayIndex];
        seg.top = this.computeDateTop(seg.start, start);
        seg.bottom = this.computeDateTop(seg.end, start);
    }
}
```

It worked.